# Laravel - Code Review

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am doing a code review in a php Laravel project. I am still relatively new to the framework. I have been using it for about 1.5+ years. I do not know all the inner workings and need some advice. I like to think i have very good handle on php though. My question is with the code below. In PHP, i would use PDO and bound parameters for everything, this code seems to be missing it. Are there any security concerns? This is in Laravel 4.2.

```
try {
    $stmt = DB::select('SELECT a.email, a.zipcode, a.is_subscribed, b.no_longer_available, b.reduced_price,b.newly_listed
                          FROM users a INNER JOIN user_preferences b ON (a.user_id = b.user_id)
                          WHERE a.user_id = "' . $this->user->user_id . '";');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

You can see the string is in the function and not bound. In laravel, shouldn't something like DB::select($sql, $params) be used?

Second question: Is the code below even valid Laravel code? I cannot find any documentation on it.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users a INNER JOIN user_preferences b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
            SET a.is_subscribed = '$is_subscribed',b.no_longer_available = '$no_longer_available',
                b.reduced_price = '$reduced_price', b.newly_listed = '$newly_listed'
            WHERE a.user_id = '$user_id';";

try 
{
    $stmt = DB::update($sql);
    $count = count($stmt);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Assume all those $variables are valid.

```
is: $stmt = DB::update($sql); even a valid Laravel function/method
```

Comment: That's wrong. Laravel has it's own prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this in a really tough way.  Laravel is setup in a way where you should think of everything in terms of objects.  It's sort of a new way of thinking of things.

So, there is a User object obviously.  You can then create more objects and define relationships between them.  For example, you could create a new Model and name it 'Preference' with a matching table containing `'user_id', 'preference_name', 'preference_value'`.

Then you could define the relationship in the User model like so:

```
public function preferences() {
    return $this->hasMany('App/Preference');
}
```

Now you would just grab a user by using `$user = User::find(1);` where 1 would be the user id.  Then you could use `$user->preferences()` and that would return all the preferences for that user.  No SQL required. TADA!  (or you could add all the preferences on the User table but that's lame)

I really hope this helps your understanding.

If you want more info, I've actually started a series on youtube.

Check it out if you want -- [Learn Laravel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDC7zBwmmThx-F02fbHVlAROwsfHhV7qW)